# Target div once user has finished dragging element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list:

```
<ul class="draggable">
    <li><span class="drag">::</span> item 1</li>
    <li><span class="drag">::</span> item 2</li>
    <li><span class="drag">::</span> item 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="done" style="display:none;">
   Yay!
</div>
```

And it is draggable via:

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
for (var i=0;i<el.length; i++) {
    var sortable = Sortable.create(el[i], {
        handle: '.drag',
        animation: 150,
        onUpdate: function (evt/**Event*/){
            var item = evt.item; // the current dragged HTMLElement

            // show .done here

        }
    });
}
```

Test [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2qnucpg/7/).

My question is, how do I show the `.done` div once the user has dragged an item?

So in onUpdate, I want to target the `.done` div. Normally, in jQuery, I would do something like:

```
jQuery(this).parent().parent().next().show();
```

But this doesn't obviously work here.

What the correct approach here? Note that I **can't** add an id to the `.done` div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.closest(selector)` along with `.next()` at this context to achieve what you want,

```
var item = evt.item; // the current dragged HTMLElement
$(item).closest(".draggable").next(".done").show();
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/h2qnucpg/8/)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much. Will accept in a moment!

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Glad to help! :)